# Get and replace quoted strings with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get strings inside a quote.
I'm using regex but i have problems with escaped quotes.

For example, i have this:

```
$var = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USERNAME='Carasuman'";
preg_match_all('~([\'"])(.*?)\1~s', $var, $result);
$new = preg_replace('~([\'"])(.*?)\1~s',"<#################>",$var);
```

The code Works perfect. I got a replaced value in $new and quoted value in $result[1]

```
$new = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USERNAME=<#################>";
$result[1] = "Carasuman";
```

My problem is when i add a scaped quote inside quotes:

```
$var = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USERNAME='Carasuman\'s'";
```

I got this:

```
$new = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USERNAME=<#################>'s";
$result[1] = "Carasuman\" //must be "Carasuman\'s";
```

How I can avoid this error and get $new and $result[1] like first example?:

```
$new = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USERNAME=<#################>";
$result[1] = "Carasuman\'s";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the positive/negative lookbehind and ignore "\'" - http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the match, you're never going to get **Carasuman's** without the \ as a single matched element since you can have match skip over chars within a single match. its either going to grab the **Carasuman** or **Carasuman\'s**
just use str_replace to get rid of the backslash

```
preg_match_all('~([\'"])(.*)\1~s', $var, $result);
$result[2] = str_replace('\\','',$result[2]);
```

for the replace, the ? in the (.*?) group makes it ungreedy, meaning it will stop at the first match. Remove the ? in (.*?) to make it greedy, meaning it will keep going until the last match

```
preg_replace('~([\'"])(.*)\1~s',"<#################>",$var);
```

**Edit**

Rather than doing the str_replace after the match on $result[2], it would probably be better to just do beforehand on the initial string like:

```
$var = str_replace("\\'","'",$var); 
preg_match_all('~([\'"])(.*)\1~s', $var, $result);
$new = preg_replace('~([\'"])(.*)\1~s',"<#################>",$var);
```

You still need to make your wildcard match greedy like (.*?) to (.*) in order to have the apostrophe in the name included in the match/replace instead of being counted as the terminating single quote

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this:

```
$var = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USERNAME='" . mysql_real_escape_string($input) . "'";
```

I don't think you necessarily need to do regex. Also, mysql_real_escape_string properly escapes your inputs so you can just have `$input = 'Carasuman\'s';` or `$input  = "Carasuman's";`

Comment: I used the example of a SQL statement to make it more visible. Not necessarily be an SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

To match quoted strings, you could use the regex `'\'.*?(?:\\\\.[^\\\\\']*)*\''` and four double quoted strings `'".*?(?:\\\\.[^\\\\"]*)*"'`